# $ionicHistory on goBack success

Tags: ionic-framework

I'd like to do something like, but goBack doesn't return promise:

```
$ionicHistory.goBack().then(function(){
$state.go('thirdState');
}
```

First state -> second state and when user call the method above -> first state and immediately go to some third state, so user can back only to first state.
When I use:

```
$ionicHistory.goBack()
$state.go('thirdState');
```

User can still go back to my second state.
What options I have to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it this way:

```
var offState = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
            function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
                $state.go('thirdState');
                offState();
            });
$ionicHistory.goBack();
```